# Flutter app check debug token: "Too many attempts"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I’m working with Flutter, and I’m trying to upload files to Firebase storage.

The upload process completed without a problem (but slowly), and the file was successfully uploaded, but in the log this appears:

> StorageUtil: Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.

I already have the debug token registered in the Firebase console and app check activate in the Flutter app, but the message is persistent.

Did I forget some step? The documentation is confusing.

Comment: Have you figure it out? My guess its just a firebase protection mode after trying to do too many getToken()

Comment: I also get this same in my console, but it doesn't cause any problems for me yet.

Comment: Can you please share all the logs you got? Logs that were printed above, after, and while the process.

Comment: Can you please share the code. If you are writing code into build() function on each state changes code runs again that may cause to upload/try each time and because its async it may cause parallel uploads of same file over and over again.

Be sure that upload code is not in build() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a daily limit quota which restricts user from attempting too many requests at a time. You must have attempted sign-up too many times or other request.
Refer below screenshot so that you can change the settings on your Firebase console

[image]